# ST_Voronoi is creating invalid geometries

Tags: postgis, postgresql, voronoi-thiessen

I have a workflow where I am creating Voronoi polygons from a series of points. However since the polygons on the exterior extend really far out I have clipped them and then joined them back to points to get the IDs back. However when I join them back based on a ST_Intersects about 1-2% of them get lost. Here is the original Voronoi polygons and then after the intersection.

[image: Voronoi before cliping]

[image: Voronoi after clipping and ST_intersects]

Here is the code that I am using

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW voronoi_test AS
WITH voronoi_temp2 AS (
    SELECT (ST_dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(ST_Collect(the_geom)))).geom as the_geom
    FROM ways_vertices_pgr)
SELECT id, voronoi_temp2.the_geom
FROM voronoi_temp2  
JOIN ways_vertices_pgr
ON ST_Intersects(ways_vertices_pgr.the_geom, voronoi_temp2.the_geom);
```

Upon further inspection of the geometries those that drop out have duplicated points. So something like [(0, 0), (1, 0.5), (1, 0.5), (0, 1), (0, 0)]. So they are self-intersecting and invalid. I have tried MakeValid and RemoveRepeatedPoints but both end up dropping the invalid polygons.

This only occurs when the data is in a geographic coordinate system and not when in a projected coordinate system.

Comment: Do you get the missing triangles if you use ST_Disjoint instead of ST_Intersects?

Comment: I do get the triangle with disjoint, but I am not sure why. If I create voronoi polygons from points they 100% should intersect with the points.

Comment: I agree that they should. Disjoint is opposite to Intersects so at least PostGIS seems to behave in a logical way. I would try to select the geometries of the disjoint triangles as WKT and check if geometries are closed.

Comment: Upon further inspection I found that they are self-intersecting. I have tried MakeValid and buffering them by 0 to fix them but both of those drop some of the rows.

Comment: You should edit the title of your question because ST_Intersects seems to work correctly.

Comment: If you have a repeatable test case that generates invalid geometry, you should open a ticket (or at least, add that info to this page). I cannot repeat your result from synthetic data. `with polys as (select (st_dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(st_collect(st_makepoint(s/0.2, t/0.2))))).geom as geom from generate_series(1,50) s, generate_series(1,50) t) select st_astext(geom), st_isvalid(geom) from polys;`

Comment: Is there any way to get the original id from `(ST_dump(ST_VoronoiPolygons(ST_Collect(the_geom))))` in order not use the "expensive" st_intersects" while joining the data back on in the end?

Comment: If there is a way to get the original id out I would love to use that instead but I am not seen anything like that. But I am still rather new to postgis.

Comment: There is not. For one, a Voronoi polygon may represent more than one input ID (for example, if the points are identical within a given tolerance.)